# Field types of query result and registered TableSink do not match

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

The query result schema  printed by table.printSchema():

```
 |-- deviceId: BIGINT
 |-- channel: STRING
 |-- schemaId: BIGINT
 |-- productId: BIGINT
 |-- schema: LEGACY('RAW', 'ANY<com.yunmo.iot.schema.Schema>')
```

bug when excuting table.toRetractStream[DeviceSchema].print(), exception throwed:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Field types of query result and registered TableSink  do not match.
Query schema: [deviceId: BIGINT, channel: STRING, schemaId: BIGINT, productId: BIGINT, schema: RAW('com.yunmo.iot.schema.Schema', ?)]
Sink schema: [deviceId: BIGINT, channel: STRING, schemaId: BIGINT, productId: BIGINT, schema: LEGACY('RAW', 'ANY<com.yunmo.iot.schema.Schema>')]
```

The com.yunmo.iot.schema.Schema is a generic type.

The schema field of Query schema change from LEGACY('RAW' to RAW, but the Sink schema still a LEGACY('RAW'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the type system rework of Flink's Table & SQL API is not completed yet and maybe not all layers play nicely together. How did you define your data type? Are you mixing `DataType` and the deprecated `Types`? Using `Types` consistently should solve the problem for now. Otherwise, feel free to open an issue on Flink's issue tracker.

Comment: I didn't use either DataType or Types, just call the fromDataStream and toRetractStream.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you created an issue about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16269.
And yes, this is a bug in blink planner, we will fix it in 1.10.1. You can use old planner as a workaround now.